# Strange Cursor Movements in NCurses (C)

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm having issues with NCurses moving the curser to the wrong place. I have no idea why its happening. Every time I enter a  key, the cursor moves 1 place further to the left until it gets to the left and just stays there. In theory, the cursor should be set to y=1, x=3 every time the loop loops.

Something of note is that when I add move(0, 0) to the end of the loop it seems to fix it but I'm just a bit confused as to why it's doing it in the first place.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

    initscr();
    clear();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    nodelay(stdscr, 1);

    bool running = 1;
    int chr;
    while(running && (chr = getch()) != '\n'){
        mvaddch(1, 3, chr);
    }
    curs_set(2);

    getch();
    clrtoeol();
    refresh();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

I should probably say what I want it to do as it seems like this is an expected result. I want to print the char at the point y=1, x=3 every time. for whatever reason, the x value changes every time the character being added changes.

**Final Edit**

changeing `mvaddch(1, 3, chr);` to `if(chr != ERR) mvaddch(1, 3, chr);` fixed the issue.

Comment: It does what is expected here (that is, nothing, except when hitting Enter). Have you tried on different Terminal emulators?

Comment: Aside: `getch` returns an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: @chrslg I'm sure it is expected I just want to know why.

Comment: I get that. That is even the only reason I upvoted the question: because I like that you are not just happy with a solution, but want to understand the problem. But since it works here, it seems that problem may has to be found elsewhere than in the code. Hence question about Terminal. But it could also be a version problem. Or ... Just it is unlikely (not impossible. For example if behavior is unspecified for some of your code, then it could work by accident here, and not on your machine) that problem is in the code.

Comment: And just now, rici's answer provides a reason why it could come from your code after all :). Since, precisely, there is an unexpected behavior when mvaddch is called with a non-char such as ERR.

Comment: @chrslg yeah thanks I was able to work it out from their answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, you choose to set the [`nodelay` option](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay):

> nodelay
>
> - The `nodelay` option causes getch to be a non-blocking call.  If no input is ready, getch returns ERR.  If disabled (bf is  `FALSE`),  `getch`  waits until a key is pressed.

So `getch` does *not* wait for a character to be pressed, and thus normally returns `ERR`. The expectation is that you never provide `ERR` or `EOF` as an argument to `mvaddch`; if you do that, all bets are off. On my system, it just continually overwrites with a grey box.

Try removing the call to `nodelay`.

Comment: Ah, I do need to use nodelay but your pointing out of ERR not working with mvaddch allowed me to come to an answer. I just put an if statement that stops it adding the character if it's == ERR.

Comment: @SuitYourself: OK, that will work but it means that you are wasting all your machine's cycles busy looping. Perhaps your actual loop is more subtle. There are use cases for `nodelay`, certainly, but if most of them involve using `select` or equivalent to avoid immediately repeating the check.

Comment: is there a better way of taking inputs that doesn't wait for user input? The loop would be used for other things as well so it's not just needlessly looping until it gets a return.

Comment: @SuitYourself: Event loops are a very common programming idiom. The usual implementation requires you to consolidate waiting for different events; if all the events are I/O related, you can do that with `select` or `poll` or a variety of other kernel mechanisms (depending on platform). There are frameworks which can help you get a good cross-platform implementation and include other event types; see, for example, `libevent` and `libuv`, for example. (Both found on github; descriptions on wikipedia.)